# Find the probability it takes at least 14 draws to find the third prize ticket.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem statement is:

A box contains $20$ tickets including $5$ prize tickets. Draw a ticket from the box sequentially without replacement. Find the probability that it takes

(a) At most $5$ draws to find the second prize ticket

(b) At least $14$ draws to find the third prize ticket

What I have tried initially:

For (a), I summed up P(2) + P(3) + ... + P(5), where P(2) was $\left( \frac{5}{20} \right)\left( \frac{4}{19} \right)$, P(3) was $\left( \frac{15}{20} \right) \left( \frac5{19}\right)\left(\frac4{18}\right)*2$, and so on up to P(5), where I got a solution of about 0.366099.

Similarly for (b), I did the same thing where I summed up P(14) + ... + P(18), and I stopped at 18 since there is a 100% chance to find all 3 by the 18th draw. The calculations were tedious, and I got roughly 0.206783348.

Then after finding those answers, I figured the numbers were a little high, so I tried a different way just using combination notation.

For (a) I tried $\left( \frac{[(5 C 2) + (5 C 3) + (5 C 4) + (5 C 5)]/}{(20 C 5)}\right)$

and for (b) I tried $\left( \frac{[(6 C 2) + (6 C 3) + (6 C 4) + (6 C 5)]/}{(20 C 6)}\right)$

Both of which gave me approximately P(a) = 0.001676987, and P(b) = 0.001444788. Now those answers seemed a little low. I don't have the solutions, so I am not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: A more convenient approach for part (a) rather than adding several probabilities together is to notice that if we were to continue drawing tickets even beyond where we would have stopped, we will have found the second prize ticket within the first five draws if and only if we didn't find only zero or one prize ticket within the first five draws.  $1-\frac{\binom{15}{5}\binom{5}{0}+\binom{15}{4}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{20}{5}}=\frac{473}{1292}\approx 0.366099$

Comment: Using a similar approach, to require at least 14 draws to find three will mean that in the first 13 draws there are exactly zero, one or two prize tickets.  I'm getting the same answers as your first attempts for both problems.  As for your second approach, I do not see where you got the idea to use the terms appearing on numerator, but it appears as though you are forgetting to account for which specific non-prize tickets were selected while pulling tickets.

Answer (score 1):

For (b), you were possibly trying to focus solely on the prize winning tickets,
in which case you also need to consider that some such may also be in the first $13$ slots, thus

$\dfrac{\binom73\binom{13}2 +\binom74\binom{13}1 + \binom75}{\binom{20}5}$